# Como selecionar um campo com MAX()+1 e usar em um INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$Position = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(OrderTask)+1 as OrderNew FROM tasks");
        $Position->execute();       
        $newPosition = $Position->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $newPosition = $row['OrderNew'];

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (Project, CompanyFantasy, Priorities, Delivery, Attachment, ByUser, Systems, OrderTask, Subject) VALUES 
                                    (:project, :companyfantasy, :priorities, :delivery, :attachment, :byuser, :systems, :ordertask, :subject)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":project", $project);         
        $stmt->bindparam(":companyfantasy", $companyfantasy);
        $stmt->bindParam(":priorities", $priorities);
        $stmt->bindParam(":delivery", $delivery);           
        $stmt->bindparam(":attachment", $file_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":byuser", $byuser);           
        $stmt->bindParam(":systems", $systems);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ordertask", $newPosition);
        $stmt->bindParam(":subject", $subject);         
        $stmt->execute();
```

O `$Position`: Faz o `SELECT` da linha `OrderTask`, dentro da tabela `Tasks`, onde pega o ultimo número, adiciona +1 e grava em OrderNew.

O `$newPosition` : Guarda o valor de `$Position`.

Mas quando eu tento jogar o retorno do `$newPosition` dentro do `INSERT` esse valor sempre é 'NULL'.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como pegar o valor do `OrderTask` e adicionar +1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passa o seu select dentro do seu insert,

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (Project, CompanyFantasy, Priorities, Delivery, Attachment, ByUser, Systems, OrderTask, Subject) VALUES 
                                    (:project, :companyfantasy, :priorities, :delivery, :attachment, :byuser, :systems, (select OrderTask from (SELECT MAX(OrderTask)+1 as OrderTask FROM tasks) X), :subject)");
```

e não precisaria mais passar o parâmetro

```
 $stmt->bindParam(":ordertask", $newPosition);
```

Comment: Ele apresenta o seguinte erro `Erro: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'tasks' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: fiz uma correção.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo dessa forma.

Comment: Você pode explicar porque o X no final do select?

Comment: o [MySQl não aceita alteração da mesma tabela](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45498/2740371) em uma unica instrução, mas aceita uma tabela temporária da mesma tabela, ou seja, fiz um sub select do select da sua tabela e renomeie como X poderia ser **abacate**.

Comment: Tabela ou campo?

Comment: Tabela, você não pode usar a mesma tabela para altera ou incluir  um campo da mesma tabela.

Answer (score 2):

`fetchAll()` Retorna um array na seguinte estrutura:   `[0] => array(OrderNew => 10)` para acessa é necessário especificar o indice zero `$row[0]['OrderNew'];`

Como o retorno é sempre uma linha troque `fetchAll()` por `fetch()` que retorna apenas uma linha, então o acesso pode ser 'direto' ex: `$row['OrderNew'];`

Comment: Não tinha reparado, mas tinha feito `fetchAll()` para teste, mas mesmo como `fetch()` retorna sempre zero.

Comment: @WagnerViana vc está usando `FETCH_ASSOC` ou `FETCH_NUM`? se for o segundo basta trocar `$row['OrderNew']` por `$row[0]`

Comment: Estou usando `FETCH_NUM` e já coloquei `FETCH_ASSOC` e os dois voltam NULL, mesmo colocando `$row['OrderNew]` ou `$row[0]`.

Comment: @WagnerViana faça `print_r($Position->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM));` e coloca aqui o resultado.

Comment: Apenas `Array()`